# How do I send direct message to a person on slack who belongs to another organization via Python code?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

How do I send direct message to a person on slack who belongs to another organization via Python code?

I am using slack_dev. I am not able to find any documentation regarding this. When I try to send a message to my target user(from another organization) using his user_id from my Python code, it shows an error "Channel not found".
Otherwise, if that user is present in my organization, the same code seems to be running fine.
Please help.
[image] On this link, I have provided my code image.

Comment: Is the user in a Workspace that has a shared channel with your organization? Or is the user fully external from your own workspace?

Comment: Yes! The user I want to connect to is a part of another Workspace, but does not have a shared channel with my own organization. So yes, he is fully external from my own workspace.

Comment: You can only DM a user from an external workspace if your app is installed in that user's workspace. The reason you are getting a channel not found error is because your bot user does not have access to that channel. Your app need to be installed and authenticated into the other workspace and you'll then be granted a new token. You'll use the token from the new workspace to make a call to chat.postMessage.